# Set a variable in RxJava before flattening

Tags: rx-java

Observable<Foo> is returned from the call to getSomething().  Foo has a list in it that is basically the data I want.  I need to filter the list so I flatten it.  However, I need another piece of data from Foo to set a variable in subscribe.onNext(). The variable I want to set is a member of a kotlin class with a default setter. I did try to return@map from map, but this seems to stop the emission, making the filter unusable.  I did look at the Pair and nested Observable suggestions in other threads, but have not found it was helpful.  I also looked at flatMapIterable's second overloaded version with a Func2, but did not get it to spit limit out.  How do I correctly apply any of the above in this case or is there another, simpler solution?

```
    service.getSomething()
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())

            ---> here I need to set limit = Foo.data.limit 

                        .flatMapIterable { t -> t.data.results }
                        .filter({ s -> filterLogic(s) })
                        .toList()
   .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                        .subscribe(
                                { c ->   //this is the list, not Foo
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to make you list flatten using Rx and then filter it. You can use Kotlin's **List.filter** function instead. You final code can look like this:

```kotlin
service.getSomething()
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .map {
        Pair(Foo.data.results.filter(this::filterLogic), Foo.data.limit)
    }
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe { (filteredResults, limit) ->
    }
```

Comment: Aha.  I knew it would be simple.  The Pair is used to pass back both items and filter is not the only way to stop emitting down to the observable.  very good, thanks.